# How can I handle non-negative mods?

Tags: java, modulo

When I use the operator % in my Java programs, I keep getting negative answers. Example: -1%100 gives -1. While this is mathematically correct, I want to get the normal mathematical solution, or 99. In other words, I want to get the smallest positive integer solution. Is there any simple solution for this in Java (perhaps something I overlooked in Math? -- I can't find it)?

I also want to clarify that if there is something in the API that does this, a link would be awesome.

Comment: The mathematically correct solution ***is*** the normal mathematical solution. You didn't ask your question clearly but sounds like you want to take the absolute value of your variable before mod'ing it.

Comment: @Perception, he means that he wants the remainder-on-division in the sense of the division algorithm. That is, he wants a solution between 0 and 99, inclusive. Most mathematicians (as distinct from computer scientists) would see this as being the more meaningful notion of remainder.

Comment: I've always done it in math classes as the least positive integer solution. But also, -1 mod 100 != 1 mod 100. Is that what you meant?

Comment: See also [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do this?

```
int d = 100;

int x = -1 % d;
if (x < 0)
    x += d;
```

This should work for any positive `d`.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately. 100 won't always be the mod. It varies.

Comment: Do you need to handle a negative modulus?

Comment: The if-statement is applied after the modulus. So it shouldn't be less than -99.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but I was wondering if there's something in the API that does this for me?

Comment: The modulus will return no less than -99. So no more than one add-back should ever be needed.

Comment: Right. My bad. But I'd still like to find a solution that's in the API if possible...

Comment: I'm not aware of an API for this, since it seems a bit trivial.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
int myMod(int x, int modulo)
{
   return ((x % modulo) + modulo)  % modulo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, for any values in place of d or x.

```
int d=100;
int x=-1%d;
while (x<0)
    x+=d;
```

Comment: Did you just copy my answer and change the formatting? (EDIT: Nevermind, you changed the `if` to a `while`. See the comments on my answer...)

Answer (score 0):

```
i < 0 ? n - ((-i - 1) % n + 1) : i % n
```

For example:

```
class Mod {
  public static int mod(int i, int n) {
    return i < 0 ? n - ((-i - 1) % n + 1) : i % n;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    System.out.println("mod(-201, 100) == " + mod(-201, 100));
    System.out.println("mod(-200, 100) == " + mod(-200, 100));
    System.out.println("mod(17, 100) == " + mod(17, 100));
    System.out.println("mod(100, 100) == " + mod(100, 100));
  }
}
```

And

```
$ javac Mod.java && java Mod
mod(-201, 100) == 99
mod(-200, 100) == 0
mod(17, 100) == 17
mod(100, 100) == 0
```

No loops.

Comment: This does not work if i % n is 0 and i < 0; e.g. mod(-200, 100) == 100 instead of 0.